# Cascading and Reveal for Java

Tags: arrays, methods, recursion, char, minesweeper

I am making a Java Mine Sweeper program. So far everything is going well except for the cascading and reveal. I keep on getting StackOverFlowError. Can someone take a look and help me? Thanks!

```
public static char[][]revealCell(int xbox, int ybox, char blankboard [] [], char     RevealedBoard [][]){


if( RevealedBoard[ybox][xbox]== 'B'){
blankboard[ybox][xbox]= 'B';
return blankboard;

}else if( RevealedBoard[ybox][xbox]== '1'){
blankboard[ybox][xbox]= '1';
return blankboard;
}

else if( RevealedBoard[ybox][xbox]== '2'){
blankboard[ybox][xbox]= '2';
return blankboard;

}else{
blankboard[ybox][xbox]= '-';

    if( xbox== 0){ // left of the grid 


        if(ybox==0){
        blankboard= revealCell(xbox+1, ybox, blankboard, RevealedBoard);
        blankboard= revealCell(xbox, ybox+1, blankboard, RevealedBoard);
        blankboard= revealCell(xbox+1, ybox+1, blankboard, RevealedBoard);
        return blankboard;
        }else if( ybox== 7){
        blankboard= revealCell(xbox+1, ybox, blankboard, RevealedBoard);
        blankboard= revealCell(xbox, ybox-1, blankboard, RevealedBoard);
        blankboard= revealCell(xbox+1, ybox-1, blankboard, RevealedBoard);              
        return blankboard;
        }else{
        blankboard= revealCell(xbox+1, ybox, blankboard, RevealedBoard);
        blankboard= revealCell(xbox, ybox-1, blankboard, RevealedBoard);
        blankboard= revealCell(xbox +1, ybox-1, blankboard, RevealedBoard);
        blankboard= revealCell(xbox, ybox+1, blankboard, RevealedBoard);
        blankboard= revealCell(xbox+1, ybox+1, blankboard, RevealedBoard);
        return blankboard;
        }

    }else if(xbox== 7){// right of the grid
    blankboard= revealCell(xbox-1, ybox, blankboard, RevealedBoard);

        if(ybox== 7){
        blankboard= revealCell(xbox, ybox-1, blankboard, RevealedBoard);
        blankboard= revealCell(xbox-1, ybox-1, blankboard, RevealedBoard);
        return blankboard;
        }else if( ybox==0){                                                             
        blankboard= revealCell(xbox, ybox+1, blankboard, RevealedBoard);
        blankboard= revealCell(xbox-1, ybox+1, blankboard, RevealedBoard);
        return blankboard;
        }else{
        blankboard= revealCell(xbox-1, ybox-1, blankboard, RevealedBoard);
        blankboard= revealCell(xbox-1, ybox+1, blankboard, RevealedBoard);
        blankboard= revealCell(xbox, ybox-1, blankboard, RevealedBoard);
        blankboard= revealCell(xbox, ybox+1, blankboard, RevealedBoard);
        return blankboard;
        }

    }else{
        if(ybox== 0){
        blankboard= revealCell(xbox-1, ybox, blankboard, RevealedBoard);
        blankboard= revealCell(xbox, ybox+1, blankboard, RevealedBoard);
        blankboard= revealCell(xbox-1, ybox+1, blankboard, RevealedBoard);
        return blankboard;
        }else if( ybox==7){
        blankboard= revealCell(xbox-1, ybox, blankboard, RevealedBoard);
        blankboard= revealCell(xbox, ybox-1, blankboard, RevealedBoard);
        blankboard= revealCell(xbox-1, ybox-1, blankboard, RevealedBoard);
        return blankboard;
        }else{
    blankboard= revealCell(xbox, ybox-1, blankboard, RevealedBoard);
    blankboard= revealCell(xbox-1, ybox-1, blankboard, RevealedBoard);
    blankboard= revealCell(xbox+1, ybox-1, blankboard, RevealedBoard);
    blankboard= revealCell(xbox-1, ybox+1, blankboard, RevealedBoard);
    blankboard= revealCell(xbox, ybox+1, blankboard, RevealedBoard);
    blankboard= revealCell(xbox-1, ybox, blankboard, RevealedBoard);
    blankboard= revealCell(xbox+1, ybox, blankboard, RevealedBoard);
    blankboard= revealCell(xbox+1, ybox+1, blankboard, RevealedBoard);

    }
    }



}
return blankboard;
}

}
```

revealCell is my method and for my actual class at school we have to use recursion. I thought this is what we should do but I am getting errors.

Comment: Manually specifying every direction to check in multiple places is ugly. Use an enumeration solution like this: http://pastebin.com/06yNW2TD And write a method that checks if the access will be out of bounds, and just does nothing if it won't be. Then in every place you can try all directions in the same `Direction` enumeration loop.

Answer (score 0):

Check the stop conditions of your recursion, are you sure that you can only get 'B', '1' or '2', what happens when a cell has 3 mines? By the way, I think your recursion can be simplified if for every cell revealing you check all your neighbors (including the out of bounds) and at the beginning of your function you check if is a valid cell ((xbox >=0 && xbox <=7) ||(ybox>=0 && ybox<=7)), if it is not a valid cell return the array as it is.

Comment: ok thanks man I actually was able to fix it by checking the stop conditions and editing some if statments. Thanks for your input!